# Material-UI + React: Why doesn't <Table/>'s onRowSelection work for Select All?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

Using Material-UI's `<Table/>` (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table) with ReactJS, I have a table set up with a select all checkbox. Every time a checkbox for a row is clicked on individually, the row id gets adds to the state array `clickedRowIds`. So `console.log()`, prints out an array with the ids of the clicked on row/s.

For example, if I were to check off the checkboxes just for the first row and second, the console log would print: `____THESE ARE THE CLICKED ROWS____ [1, 2]` (With 1 and 2 representing the row ID numbers in integer). But when I click on the Select All checkbox in the header, it checks off all the checkboxes in the table, yet in the `console.log()`, it just shows `____THESE ARE THE CLICKED ROWS____ all` and `ids.forEach()` gets an error `Uncaught TypeError: ids.forEach is not a function`.

The row checkboxes are all being clicked on via Select All checkbox, but why aren't all the row ID numbers being added to the `clickedRowIds` array? Using `ids.forEach()`, I would like to console log all the selected rows using Select All button.

```
export default class TestTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      clickedRowIds: [],
    }

    this.handleRowSelection = this.handleRowSelection.bind(this);
  }

  handleRowSelection(rowIds) {
    this.setState({
      clickedRowIds: rowIds
    })
  }

  render(){
    const ids = this.state.clickedRowIds
    console.log('____THESE ARE THE CLICKED ROWS____ ', ids)

    ids.forEach(id => {console.log(id)})

    return(

      <div className='table_body' style={styles.content}>
        <Table
          multiSelectable={true}
          onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection}
        >
          <TableHeader
            displaySelectAll={true}
            enableSelectAll={true}
          >
              ...
          </TableHeader>
        </Table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer will be upvoted and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs here: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table

> Called when a row is selected. selectedRows is an array of all row
>   selections. IF all rows have been selected, the string "all" will be
>   returned instead to indicate that all rows have been selected.

This means that if all rows are selected, annoyingly, your rowIds will no longer be set to an array, but a string saying "all".  You'll need some logic to handle that case before calling forEach on rowIds. Your error is due to the string "all" not having the `forEach` method available.